# height animation is not working in CSS sample

Tags: css, animation, height

Does anybody know why the height animation is not working on this example and causes this "jump" on the animation?

```
transition: height .5s;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0a72pr9g/16/

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Add `!importan` to override

Comment: Thanks for the reply Salomon. I just checked (I guess your save) http://jsfiddle.net/0a72pr9g/18 with important added, but this hasn't changed anything I think and I tested it in multiple browsers.

Comment: Also notice you can use "all" eg transition: all 1s ease-out;
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @CarolMcKay but I think that wouldn't be as efficient and I might accidentally animate something I wasn't intended to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One transition was cancelling out the other, and the other, you need to do it like this:

```
.box {
   transition: height .5s, margin .5s, transform .5s;
}
```

NOT like this:

```
.box {
   transition: height .5s;
   transition: margin .5s;
   transition: transform .5s;
}
```

linky: https://jsfiddle.net/0a72pr9g/26/

Comment: many thanks for the reply Carol! I did figure it out eventually, but it was a bit confusing as most examples I've seen online, has the animations separate. :/

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution! I switched from this

```
transition: height .5s;
transition: margin .5s;
transition: transform .5s;
```

to this (I've added a few more animations but it's unrelated)

```
transition: height .25s, margin .25s, transform .25s, background .25s, color .25s;
```

and that fixed the issue! If anybody knows why, I would love to know.

Here's the updated example.

http://jsfiddle.net/0a72pr9g/23/

Thanks